# Perda de privilégios ao oferecer recompensas

Tags: suporte

Imaginei que essa pergunta fosse ser duplicada, mas nada que me respondesse foi sugerido.

Ao atingir **500** pontos de reputação, eu ganho o privilégio de acessar as filas de análise. Eu nunca ofereci uma recompensa em pergunta, então, gostaria de saber o que acontece no seguinte cenário:

1 - Atingi 510 pontos de reputação

2 - Ofereci 50 pontos de reputação em uma pergunta (me restam 460 pontos)

Nesse caso, eu perco o privilégio das filas de análise?

Em outra situação que pensei agora. Caso eu tenha 105 pontos de reputação, e tenha feito vários votos (a favor e contra) e ofereça 100 pontos de recompensa em uma pergunta (me restam 5 pontos de reputação). Como ficam os votos que eu já dei?